# Implementing a concept for Pair with C++20 concepts

Tags: c++, c++20, c++-concepts

To print any kind of `std::pair` we can implement the following method:

```
template<typename First, typename Second>
void printPair(const std::pair<First, Second>& p) {
    std::cout << p.first << ", " << p.second << std::endl;
}
```

But suppose we want to implement a method that can print a pair of any kind, not necessarily `std::pair`, based on the following requirements:

- it has a `first` and `second` public fields
- it has a `first_type` and `second_type` public inner types
- type of `first` == `first_type`
- type of `second` == `second_type`

Having a `concept`, let's call it **Pair**, could allow writing a method like:

```
void printPair(const Pair auto& p) {
    std::cout << p.first << ", " << p.second << std::endl;
}
```

How would such a `concept` be defined?

Comment: Why would someone make such a type to begin with? `std::pair` is just not a good idea. Concepts should be only as specific as is *necessary*. Better to check for its tuple-like interface, like `get`, `tuple_element`, and the like.

Comment: @NicolBolas this is a valuable comment, added an answer in that spirit

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There are some interesting subtleties here.

```
template<class P>
concept Pair = requires(P p) {
    typename P::first_type;
    typename P::second_type;
    p.first;
    p.second;
    requires std::same_as<decltype(p.first), typename P::first_type>;
    requires std::same_as<decltype(p.second), typename P::second_type>;
};
```

The first four lines are somewhat redundant, but can help produce better error messages. 
The remaining lines should be self-explanatory. Note that the use of `decltype` on a plain class member access produces the declared type of the data member.

The last two lines could also be written as

```
    { p.first } -> std::same_as<typename P::first_type&>;
    { p.second } -> std::same_as<typename P::second_type&>;
```

Here, the *compound-requirement* applies the *type-constraint* to `decltype((p.first))`. That expression is an lvalue, so the produced type is an lvalue reference type. Note that this version would accept both `first_type first;` and `first_type& first;`.

Comment: why do the firs four lines produce better error messages?

Answer (score 4):

Following @Nicol Bolas comment on the original question I agree that narrowing the `concept` to allow only Pair that conforms to `std::pair` requirements is not the best design, it would be better to allow all the following:

- `std::pair` and similar classes with `first` and `second` fields
- `std::tuple` of size 2, `std::array` of size 2 and similar classes

It is true that `std::pair` falls in both categories, as it proposes tuple-like syntax, however we wish to be able to accommodate user types that expose *first* and *second* fields but do not implement a tuple-like syntax.

For that we can implement two separate concepts and then use conjunction to create a third one:

---

### 1. SimplePair `concept`

```
template<class P>
concept SimplePair = requires(P p) {
    p.first;
    p.second;
};
```

---

### 2. TuplePair `concept`

```
template<class P>
concept TuplePair = requires(P p) {
    requires std::tuple_size<P>::value == 2;
    std::get<0>(p);
    std::get<1>(p);
};
```

^ above supports also std::array

---

### 3. Pair `concept`

```
template<class P>
concept Pair = TuplePair<P> || SimplePair<P>;
```

---

Now we can have a generic **printPair**, using `requires clause` inside `if constexpr`:

```
void printPair(const Pair auto& p) {
    if constexpr( SimplePair<decltype(p)> ) {
        std::cout << p.first << ", " << p.second << std::endl;
    }
    else {
        std::cout << std::get<0>(p) << ", " << std::get<1>(p) << std::endl;
    }
}
```

---

### usage example

```
struct MyPair {
    int first = 5;
    const char* second = "six";
};

int main() {
    printPair(std::make_tuple(1, "two")); // 1, two
    printPair(std::make_pair(3, 4));      // 3, 4
    printPair(MyPair{});                  // 5, six
    printPair(std::array{7, 8});          // 7, 8
    // not allowed, compilation error:
    // printPair(std::array{9, 10, 11});
    // printPair(std::make_tuple("one"));
    // printPair(std::make_tuple(1, 2, 3));
}
```

Code: https://godbolt.org/z/MXgqu3

Comment: This `Pair` concept requires way to much work to actually utilize, basically requiring two entirely separate implementations of any code that tries to use it. My point with my comment is that you *shouldn't* be using the `first`/`second` interface of `std::pair` at all; it *already* satisfies the tuple-like interface, so generic could should just use that.

Comment: What about using structured binding or `std::tie` to simplify the function implementation?

Comment: @AmirKirsh
`void printPair(const Pair auto& p) {
    const auto& [first, second] = p;
    std::cout << first << ", " << second << std::endl;

}`

https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/DfHXCM

Comment: @YehezkelB. good suggestion, it works nicely even with a user Pair with inner proxy for lazy evaluation: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f6ad63708275da81

Answer (score 1):

**Old Syntax - for Historical Purposes**

The code below was valid at a certain point of time with early versions of  *Concepts Technical Specification*, and compiles with experimental implementation, but was changed in later versions of the TS and is no longer valid with the C++20 spec. It is kept here for *historical reasons* and as a note on the change in the spec.

---

Old version of Concepts TS had the following syntax:

```
template<typename _pair>
concept Pair = requires(_pair p) {
    { p.first } -> typename _pair::first_type;
    { p.second } -> typename _pair::second_type;
};
```

Above syntax is **not valid** in C++20. For the valid C++20 syntax see the other answers for this question.

---

This would allow a generic printPair to work for `std::pair` as well as for any other user "pair" that conforms with Pair requirements:

```
void printPair(const Pair auto& p) {
    std::cout << p.first << ", " << p.second << std::endl;
}

struct UserPair {
    int first = 1;
    const char* second = "hello";
    using first_type = decltype(first);
    using second_type = decltype(second);
};

int main() {
    printPair(std::make_pair(1, 3));
    printPair(UserPair{});
}
```

A working code example with *old version of the TS*: https://godbolt.org/z/x6f76D

Comment: Using `std::declval` is redundant. `requires(_pair p) { { p.first } -> ...` works just fine even if the object is not default-constructible.

Comment: Is `{ p.first } -> typename _pair::first_type;` really going to work? Doesn't the `->` require that the right hand side operand is also a `concept`?

Comment: @Fureeish, Yes, you now have to be explicit and say `-> std::convertible_to<blah>`.

Comment: @Fureeish, It shouldn't unless something changed very last minute that I didn't hear about, but I expect implementations might lag behind on this one for a little while yet.

Comment: Thank you @Fureeish, chris and T.C. this syntax used to be valid at a certain point of time based on some previous version of the spec - I'm keeping this answer with a relevant edit note to document the fact that it is not a valid syntax anymore, which may help others.

Answer (score 0):

I really liked this question and the discussions around it, specially the solution from T.C (I don't have 50 points to comment there, so I'll post comments as another solution).
I just passed from a similar situation, where a pair concept is need, but also needed the library to work on both C++17 and C++20.

This solution from T.C. works for both c++17 and c++20.

```cpp
template<class P>
concept bool Pair = requires(P p) {
    typename P::first_type;
    typename P::second_type;
    p.first;
    p.second;
    requires my_same_as<decltype(p.first), typename P::first_type>;
    requires my_same_as<decltype(p.second), typename P::second_type>;
};
```

where `my_same_as` is defined as `std::same_as` from c++20:

```cpp
template<class Me, class Other>
  concept bool my_same_as = std::is_same_v<Me, Other> && std::is_same_v<Other, Me>;
```

I've tried several "implementations of pairs" and interesting point is that fields `first` and `second` may vary from reference or not-reference types.

T.C. mentioned that we could replace fields with:

```
    { p.first } -> my_same_as<typename P::first_type&>;
    { p.second } -> my_same_as<typename P::second_type&>;
```

I found out that this only works on c++20, strangely not on c++17 (it compiles fine, but doesn't match concept!). Somehow it doesn't match either reference or non-reference (requiring complex implementation with an `||` and `std::remove_reference_t`).

One portable solution that I found for both c++17 and c++20 was:

```cpp
template<typename P>
concept bool Pair = requires(P p)
{   
    typename P::first_type;
    typename P::second_type;
    { p.first } -> my_convertible_to<typename P::first_type>;
    { p.second } -> my_convertible_to<typename P::second_type>;
};
```

where `my_convertible_to` is equivalent to `std::convertible_to` from c++20:

```cpp
template <class From, class To>
concept bool my_convertible_to =
  std::is_convertible_v<From, To> &&
  requires(std::add_rvalue_reference_t<From> (&f)()) {
    static_cast<To>(f());
  };
```

I cannot explain why this subtle behavior changed from c++17 to c++20 (on `is_same_v` logic), but I'm posting here as it may help others in a similar situation. I used g++-8 for c++17 and g++-10.1 for c++20. Thanks for all the learning!